# if then else statement makes exactly the same in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find what's wrong with the code but i cannot. In first if statement  i want to say if movement is ADD and if 3 cells of sheet 1 (DataEntry) are equal with 3 cells of sheet2(Catalogue) then don't do the entry else if they are not equal then do it. In both situations it does the entry and because of that i have duplicates. Can anyone help?

p.s.: if i remove the elseif and i have only if then it shows the message.

**Updated (24/1/2020)**:  Yesterday all worked fine. And a few minutes ago i realized that when i type a greek word in cells A,B,C for example "φίλτρο" "νερού" "κ.π." the excel does not recognize. Even if it seems that tries to enter the data on Catalogue sheet nothing happened and nothing appears.
Although weird things are happening. Sometimes all worked fine (except greeks), sometimes wrong message boxes appeared. And keep running and displaying the message even if i click ok and then excel crashes. "I got dizzy" and i cannot think clear.

```
Sub AddChange()
Dim t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6
Dim t10, t11, t12, t13, t14, t15
Dim t18, t19, t20, t21, t22, t23
Dim arrayData As Variant
Dim arrayData2 As Variant
Dim cleanData As Range
Dim keli As Range
Dim baseSheet As Object
Dim formaSheet As Object
Dim Stock As Object
Dim meter As Long
Dim meter2 As Long
Dim Movement As String
Dim i As Integer


    Set Stock = Sheets("StockMovements")
    Set baseSheet = Sheets("Catalogue")
    Set formaSheet = Sheets("DataEntry")
    Set t1 = formaSheet.Range("A6")
    Set t2 = formaSheet.Range("B6")
    Set t3 = formaSheet.Range("C6")
    Set t4 = formaSheet.Range("D6")
    Set t5 = formaSheet.Range("E6")
    Set t6 = formaSheet.Range("F6")
    Set t10 = baseSheet.Range("A2")
    Set t11 = baseSheet.Range("B2")
    Set t12 = baseSheet.Range("C2")
    Set t13 = baseSheet.Range("D2")
    Set t14 = baseSheet.Range("E2")
    Set t15 = baseSheet.Range("F2")

    Set t18 = Stock.Range("B2")
    Set t19 = Stock.Range("C2")
    Set t20 = Stock.Range("D2")
    Set t21 = Stock.Range("E2")
    Set t22 = Stock.Range("F2")
    Set t23 = Stock.Range("G2")

    Movement = Range("G6").Value

If Movement Like "ADD NEW" Then

 For i = 2 To 10000



    With Worksheets("DataEntry")
        If (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "A"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "A")))) _
            And (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "B"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "B")))) _
            And (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "C"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "C")))) _
        Then
            MsgBox "The product already exists! Select change and continue.", vbOKCancel

        ElseIf Not (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "A"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "A")))) _
            And (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "B"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "B")))) _
            And (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "C"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "C")))) _
        Then
             meter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(baseSheet.Range("A:A"))
             meter2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Stock.Range("A:A"))

             arrayData = VBA.Array(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6)
             'arrayData2 = VBA.Array(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6)
             Set cleanData = Union(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5)

             With cleanData.Cells
              Set keli = .Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues)
              If keli Is Nothing Then
              GoTo telos
              End If
             End With

             baseSheet.Cells(meter + 1, 1).Resize(, 6) = arrayData
             Stock.Cells(meter2 + 1, 1).Resize(, 6) = arrayData
             cleanData.ClearContents
        End If
    End With
Next i

End If



If Movement Like "CHANGE" Then


 For i = 2 To 10000



    With Worksheets("DataEntry")
    If (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "A"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "A")))) _
            And (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "B"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "B")))) _
            And (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "C"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "C")))) _
    Then

         MsgBox "Do you want to continue?", vbOKCancel
         Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "A") = Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "A")
         Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "B") = Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "B")
         Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "C") = Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "C")
         Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "D") = Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "D")
         Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "E") = Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "E")
         Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "F") = Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "F")

   ElseIf Not (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "A"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "A")))) _
            And (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "B"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "B")))) _
            And (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "C"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "C")))) _
        Then
             MsgBox "The product does not exist. Select add new.", vbOKCancel
             Set cleanData = Union(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5)

             With cleanData.Cells
              Set keli = .Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues)
              If keli Is Nothing Then
              GoTo telos
              End If
             End With
             cleanData.ClearContents
        End If
    End With
Next i

End If


telos:

End Sub
```

I type a new item and i click change, it should be poped up a message "The product does not exist. Select add new." It shows this message and then another message poped up and crashes there.
[image]

Something similar happened when i am trying to add a product that already exists. First shows the right message and then shows another and crashes.

Comment: `Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(10, "A") = Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "A")` An example: This will not be equal if there are leading or trailing spaces. If it is text then you will also have to take care of case. Try sometthing like this? `UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(10, "A"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "A")))` similarly for others...

Comment: Glad it works :)

Comment: with this code, I just found that greek characters are not recognized. Is there any way to recognize greek?

Comment: you will have to share some sample

Comment: i will edit the question and share the whole code. I didn't change anything and suddenly when i click the button nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't the greek characters.. the problem was the ElseIF Not. So i change the code with this

```
ElseIf (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "A"))) <> UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "A")))) _
        And (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "B"))) <> UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "B")))) _
    Then
```